# using limit with like keyword in mysql query gives 0 rows

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

i was trying to create a pagination for my project but , while i was trying to execute a query from java code , for getting searched keyword based rows, i am getting 0 rows. but there still more than rows are present in mysql database.

i tried mysql query like:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM books where keyword like '%java%' limit 1,5;
```

This query gives me 0 results.

while trying

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM books where keyword like '%java%' limit 5;
```

this will give me 1 result, as i am having one row corresponding to the keyword. but if the results are more than 5 then it is not displaying me more 5 results, and i want to use it for controlling pages to retrieve from databases.

any body pls help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meaning of

```
limit 1, 5
```

is,
select 2nd row onwards, a total of 5 records, if found.

But in your case, for the search criteria, as there exists only one record, and
you want from 2nd to 6th record, a total of 5 records, the result was empty.

Change:

```
limit 1,5;
```

To:

```
limit 0, 5; -- to fetch first 5 records from the found
```

Or

```
limit 5; -- to fetch first 5 records from the found
```

To find total number of found records, You need to execute

```
select found_rows()
```

when used with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

Sequence of operations should be:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM books where keyword like '%java%' limit 5;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

The second `SELECT` returns a number indicating how many rows the first `SELECT` would have returned had it been written without the `LIMIT` clause.

**Refer to**: [**MySQL: Found_Rows()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Comment: i was trying it from one day was not getting the mistack, wat i did. it works for me now. Lot of thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement paging with mysql you should consider to use a prepared statement with placeholders. E.g.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM books where keyword like ? limit ?,?;
```

and then bind the parameters. E.g.

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
              "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM books where keyword like ? limit ?,?");

int firstRow = 1;
int pageSize = 5;

ps.setString(1,"%java%");
ps.setInt(2, firstRow);
ps.setInt(3, pageSize);
```

More about that in the section "limit" of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: We can't set prepared param values for limit clause.

Comment: I was mistaken on JAVA compatibility on limit parameters. Sorry. It works.